# Wait for Database to finish inserting data before continuing to next activity Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an activity that calls JSON data from a foreign database.
Below is my ideal case for my app:

- The JSON data is parsed and inserted into an SQLite database on Android
- Next activity is started and the newly inserted data is read from the SQLite database

What actually happens:

- The JSON data is parsed and inserted into an SQLite database on Android
- The next activity is started while data is still being inserted and returns zero when reading from the desired databse for my ListArray in that activity.

How do I force Android to wait until database insertion is completed before starting the next activity?

**EDIT**

My `doInBackground` looks as follows:

> ```
> @Override
> protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
>
>         StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
>                 str, new Response.Listener<String>() {
>
>             @Override
>             public void onResponse(String response) {
>
>                 try {
>                     JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
>                     boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
>
>                     // Check for error node in json
>                     if (!error) {
>                         JSONArray jObjInside = jObj.getJSONArray("service_prov_services");
>                         for (int i = 0; i < jObjInside.length(); i++) {
>                             // Now store the user in SQLite
>                             try {
>                                 //  JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
>
>                                 String service_prov_type = jObj.getString("service_prov_type");
>                                 String service_prov_name = jObj.getString("service_prov_name");
>                                 String addr_street = jObj.getString("addr_street");
>                                 String addr_num = jObj.getString("addr_number");
>                                 String addr_plz = jObj.getString("addr_plz");
>                                 String addr_city = jObj.getString("addr_city");
>                                 JSONObject elem = jObjInside.getJSONObject(i);
>
>                                 if(elem != null){
>
>                                     String service_id = elem.getString("service_id");
>                                     String service_type = elem.getString("service_type");
>                                     String service_measure = elem.getString("service_measure");
>
>
>                                     // Inserting row in userServiceProvServices table
>                                         db.addUserServiceProvServices(service_id, service_prov_type,
>                                        service_prov_name, addr_street, addr_num, addr_plz, addr_city, service_type, service_measure);
>                                     Log.d("post_url for service", addr_plz );
>                                 }
>
>                             } catch (JSONException e) {
>                                 // JSON error
>                                 e.printStackTrace();
>                                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " +
>                              e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                             }
>                         }
>
>                     } else {
>                         // Error in login. Get the error message
>                         String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
>                         Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
>                                 errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                     }
>                 } catch (JSONException e) {
>                     // JSON error
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " +
>                                    e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 }
>
>             }
>         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
>
>             @Override
>             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>                 Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
>                 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
>                         error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>
>             }
>         });
>
>         Log.d("test string to appcntr",strReq.toString());
>         // Adding request to request queue
>         AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
>
>
>
>
>         return params[0];
>
>     }
> ```

`onPostExecute`  looks as follows:

> ```
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
>         //super.onPostExecute(Result);
>         pdLoading.dismiss();
>         //this method will be running on UI thread
>
>         Log.d(TAG, "Stamp: " + Result);
>         Bundle args = new Bundle();
>         args.putString("stampID", Result);
>
>         ProviderServiceListFragment frag = new ProviderServiceListFragment();
>         frag.setArguments(args);
>         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
>         fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
>                 .replace(R.id.content_frame,
>                         frag)
>                 .commit();
>
>
>
>     }
> ```

With the way I am doing it now, my next Fragment is already called, although the data has not finished being entered into the database. This means the ListArray in the follwoing Fragment is empty because of the missing database data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked on this for a month and finally figured it out for myself (stupid nube I am..) So here is a piece of code inserting a record to sqlite.

On the chosen event ("onClick actionbutton1") a new AsyncTask is created with doInBackground, onPreExecute and onPostExecute.

onPreExecute will setMessage() and show() the progressDialog which will start spinning

onPostExecute will handle the new/next Activity

**READ BELOW FOR doInBackground!!**

```
actionButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddUpdateEvf.this);

                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        doOneThing();
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                        progressDialog.show();

                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

                        evaluationFormOps.close();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddUpdateEvf.this);
                                        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Added to Database...")
                                                .setCancelable(false)
                                                .setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                        i = new Intent(AddUpdateEvf.this, ViewProduct.class);
                                                        i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADD_UPDATE, "View");
                                                        i.putExtra(EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID, hiddenTextId.getText().toString());
                                                        i.putExtra(EXTRA_PRODUCT_NO, productNo_tv.toString());
                                                        startActivity(i);
                                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                                        finish();
                                                    }
                                                });

                                        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                                        alert.show();

        }
                    private void doOneThing() {

                        makeDbRequest();
                        do {
                            evfId = newEvf.getEvfId();
                        }
                        while (evfId<1);
                    }

                }.execute();




            }
        });
```

**Note this snippet in the above code called in doInBackground():**

```
 private void doOneThing() {

                        makeDbRequest();
                        do {
                            evfId = newEvf.getEvfId();
                        }
                        while (evfId<1);
                    }
```

Note: The makeDbRequest() handles the insert to sqlite by setting the values and then passing it to another class which handles the cursor and puts the values etc.

Heres a small snippet of relevant code in that class (which you should already have mastered...):

```
 public Evf addEvf(Evf evf, String dBsuccess){

    ContentValues values  = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TableHelper.PRODUCT_IDE,evf.getPRODUCTId());
    values.put(TableHelper.CSCORE,evf.getcScore());
    values.put(TableHelper.FSCORE,evf.getfScore());
    values.put(TableHelper.TSCORE,evf.gettScore());
    values.put(TableHelper.WEIGHT,evf.getWeight());
    values.put(TableHelper.TEMP,evf.getTemp());
    values.put(TableHelper.STATUS,evf.getStatus());
    values.put(TableHelper.TIMESTAMP, String.valueOf(evf.getTimeStamp()));
    values.put(TableHelper.LOADED, dBsuccess);
    long insertid = database.insert(TableHelper.TABLE_EVFS,null,values);
    evf.setEvfId((int) insertid);
    return evf;

}
```

So above you can see the Id of, in my case evaluationform(Evf), being set to the insert id. This happens after the insert and you can set any value in your object class (the one with getters and setters...Evf())

**Finally, use the do...while statement above to "listen" for the value being set in the object class**

This can obviously only happen if the insert was finished and the onPosteExecute takes care of the rest

***Hope it helps, crit is welcome, PEACHES!!***

Answer (score 0):

The StringRequest is an Asynchronous request, so upon the executing the those lines onPostExecute will called immediately, so there is no guarantee that the sql update will complete before the next activity is launched.

Call the nextActivity at the end of the onResponse callback method of the StringRequest which way you can guarantee to insert the data to db first and then call the nextActivity.

```
     private void makeJsonRequest(String str) {
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                str, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        JSONArray jObjInside = jObj.getJSONArray("service_prov_services");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jObjInside.length(); i++) {
                            // Now store the user in SQLite
                            try {
                                //  JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");

                                String service_prov_type = jObj.getString("service_prov_type");
                                String service_prov_name = jObj.getString("service_prov_name");
                                String addr_street = jObj.getString("addr_street");
                                String addr_num = jObj.getString("addr_number");
                                String addr_plz = jObj.getString("addr_plz");
                                String addr_city = jObj.getString("addr_city");
                                JSONObject elem = jObjInside.getJSONObject(i);

                                if (elem != null) {

                                    String service_id = elem.getString("service_id");
                                    String service_type = elem.getString("service_type");
                                    String service_measure = elem.getString("service_measure");


                                    // Inserting row in userServiceProvServices table
                                    db.addUserServiceProvServices(service_id, service_prov_type,
                                            service_prov_name, addr_street, addr_num, addr_plz, addr_city, service_type, service_measure);
                                    Log.d("post_url for service", addr_plz);
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // JSON error
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " +
                                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        goNextActivity();

                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " +
                            e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

        Log.d("test string to appcntr", strReq.toString());
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void goNextActivity(){
        //this method will be running on UI thread
        ProviderServiceListFragment frag = new ProviderServiceListFragment();
        frag.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                        frag)
                .commit();
    }
```

Comment: @Stefan seems like you have mixed AsyncTask and Volley StringRequest, you dont need both. You can use the StringRequest and onResponse call the next fragment, let me try to answer it in code separately

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask to process the Database insertion process & then use the onPostExecute method to move away from the current activity.

```
private class ProcessDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        String sampleData;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            //Call your Database Insert method here.
            //In this example, I am inserting sampleData to the DB

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //This gets triggered when the process is complete
        }
    }
```

You can start the AsyncTask by adding the following code in your onCreate or where ever you want to start the DB Insertion process:

```
//in this case I am just passing a string, You can create your own
//custom class & send that as well
ProcessDatabase.execute(myData);
```

Refer [this link](http://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial) for more information. Good luck!